# How to run php code from symfony?

Tags: php

I'm very new to PHP and beginner to programming as well and I want to use symfony framework and I don't know how. I created a new symfony bundle in netbeans and now I can't run a php code from there. PHP code simply doesn't work, when I run it html codes are fine but PHP codes are shown raw in the browser even though I run it with XAMPP `localhost` like this `localhost/Test/web/app_dev.php/Test` Any solution? Tnx. I just found out that I can just write the php code separately from the html on the DefaultController.php and it works just fine.

Comment: What server (Apache/IIS) are you using?

Comment: the path for your project will be `http://localhost/app_dev.php/Test` in browser if you have set the document root to your project in httpd config file

Answer (score 0):

You can just try with this code,Also some Test files can extened not only `PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase class`. For example in Symfony2 there are common functional tests like this:

```
class DemoControllerTest extends WebTestCase
{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have these tags around your PHP code:

```
<?php

?>
```

Even though Symfony is a PHP framework, you still need these tags around your code.